# Calling function using double dot notation yields syntax error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've recently started doing some studying for various MCSE: BI exams. In doing so, I'm coming across aspects of SQL Server I haven't used before. Double dot notation isn't something I've used much, so this scenario struck me as a little odd.

My user's default schema is `dbo`, and all objects below create under `dbo`.

Given the following example:

```
use laboratory

create table tbl_simple_test(SimpleTestID int identity(1,1), SomeVal varchar(255))
go

insert tbl_simple_test
select 'test value 1'
go

create procedure usp_simple_procedure
AS
BEGIN

    select 1

END
go

create function fn_simple_function()
Returns int
AS
BEGIN

    Declare @Result int

    select @Result = 1

    return @Result

END
go

select * from laboratory.dbo.tbl_simple_test
--returns record we inserted above

select * from laboratory..tbl_simple_test
--returns record we inserted above

exec laboratory.dbo.usp_simple_procedure
--returns 1

exec laboratory..usp_simple_procedure
--returns 1

select laboratory.dbo.fn_simple_function()
--returns 1

select laboratory..fn_simple_function()
--syntax error
```

I did some googling and searching on SO. I came across some discussion around how naming is resolved, but I didn't see anything mentioning this "limitation". Since I can call a procedure, or select from a table, using double dot notation, why can't I call a function in a similar manner?

Comment: Does the exam specifically care? Double dot is just syntactic sugar, and the dearth of documentation around the feature should be an indicator of it's lack of use. Best practice suggest always fully qualifying your object names. I'm inclined to think it's just an oddity of the way it works, and move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scalar UDFs in SQL Server [must be prefixed by a schema identifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx).  While I cannot find a specific rationale for this, I'll speculate that it is to reduce confusion and namespace conflict between intrinsic functions (`ISNULL`, etc.) and UDFs.

The consequence of this is that double-dot notation, where you are specifying a database but using your default schema for that database, won't work for UDFs.